# C# .NET: How to add array and ask user for input?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have written this code and now I want to ask the user to select from multiple candies from a vending machine. Currently this code only represents one candy bar. I know I have to declare an array but I don't know how to ask the user to select a candy bar and return the selection:

```
    namespace CandybarVendingMachine
{

    public class VendingMachine
    {
        // private instance variables
        private int _numQuarters, _numCandyBars;

        // Public noarg constructor
        public VendingMachine()
        {
            // Set the candy bar cost in quarters.  
            _numQuarters = 3;

            // Set initial number of candy bars.
            _numCandyBars = 5;
        }

        // Public read only properties:

        public int NumQuarters
        {
            get { return _numQuarters; }
        }

        public int NumCandyBars
        {
            get { return _numCandyBars; }
        }

        // Public methods:

        public string DepositQuarter()
        {
            _numQuarters++;
            return "Quarter deposited.";
        }

        public string SelectCandy()
        {
            if (_numQuarters >= 3 && _numCandyBars > 0)
            {
                _numQuarters = _numQuarters -3;
                _numCandyBars--;
                return "Candy bar dispensed";
            }
            else if (_numCandyBars > 0)
            {
                return "Not enough quarters to buy candy bar.";
            }
            else
            {
                return "No candy bars in machine.";
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {

            return "Total Quarters: " + _numQuarters + " Total Bars:" + _numCandyBars;
        }
    }

}
```

I know I can initialize get array

```
private int[] _numCandyBars;

public VendingMachine()
{
//Number of quarters require to buy candybar
_numQuarters = 3;

//Candybar array contains 3 candy bars
_numCandyBars = new int[3];
_numCandyBars[0] = 5;
_numCandyBars[1] = 4;
_numCandyBars[2] = 3;

}
```

I need to know how can I ask the user to select a candy bar?

Comment: How do you expect users to input the answer? Do you want them to enter it into the console or do you have another way to input the data?

Comment: for now User should enter it in console but second part of this application will be implemented in c# WPF where user will be able to see picture of 3 candies and they can click on vend button under each candy to select that candy.

Comment: Have you looked into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx For me, it's unclear where/how you want to implement this. Do you have a main method somewhere?

Comment: first I need to complete console app than I will have to create wpf app

Comment: why did you vote negative to this question?
 if you have hard time understanding the question than pleas ask me to explain further.
 I'm new at this site and also new at programming.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question. However, I assume someone downvoted because the vague nature of your question or probably because it feels like you are proposing a question where you haven't really given an effort to solve the problem.

Comment: sorry I though you downvote it.
 Currently It's working with one candy where you can set number of quarters and number of candies available but I need to set the code to have selection for multiple candies. I know it will be in array but I don't know how to implement array. that's what my question is.

Comment: We can certainly implement it where it takes an array of candies, but there is still an important question. Are all candies the same price or number of quarters?

Comment: candies can be different prices but for now I just want to keep static number of candies and static number of quarters to buy candies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I just pecked out real quick (I was bored). I haven't tested it, but it should work. All you really need to do with it is write the implementation for it. You'll need a function to print the menu for the user and you;ll need to write some code to add your items to the slots. The rest should mostly be there for you. I may continue to enhance it some more, but feel free to use any or all of the following.

```
namespace VendingMachine
{
    public class Vend
    {
        private string[] VALID_ROWS = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        private string[] VALID_COLS = new string[] { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" };

        public Vend()
        {
            ProductSlot = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Item>>();
            foreach(string row in VALID_ROWS)
            {
                ProductSlot.Add(row, new Dictionary<string,Item>());
                foreach(string col in VALID_COLS)
                    ProductSlot[row].Add(col, null);
            }
        }

        public void AddProduct(string row, string col, Item item)
        {
            if (!VALID_ROWS.Contains(row)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("row", string.Format("The row provided: `{0}` is not valid.", row));
            if (!VALID_COLS.Contains(col)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("col", string.Format("The column provided: `{0}` is not valid.", col));
            ProductSlot[row][col] = item;
        }

        public double GetPrice(string row, string col)
        {
            double price = GetProduct(row, col).Price;
            return price;
        }

        public string GetProductName(string row, string col)
        {
            string name = GetProduct(row, col).ProductName;
            return name;
        }

        public int GetQuantity(string row, string col)
        {
            int qty = GetProduct(row, col).Quantity;
            return qty;
        }

        public Item PurchaseItem(string row, string col)
        {
            Item item = GetProduct(row, col);
            if (item.Quantity < 1) throw new OutOfStockException("This item is out of stock, please select another item.");
            if (CreditMoney < item.Price) throw new InsufficientFundsException("There is not enough money to purchase this item.");
            item.Quantity--;
            CreditMoney -= item.Price;
            return item;
        }

        public string PrintProductList()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string row in VALID_ROWS)
            {
                foreach (string col in VALID_COLS)
                {
                    Item item = GetProduct(row, col);
                    if (item == null) continue;
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\t{0} : {1} @ {2} ea.\t{3}", string.Concat(row, col), item.Quantity.ToString(), item.Price.ToString("C2"), item.ProductName));
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public Item GetProduct(string row, string col)
        {
            if (!VALID_ROWS.Contains(row)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("row", string.Format("The row provided: `{0}` is not valid.", row));
            if (!VALID_COLS.Contains(col)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("col", string.Format("The column provided: `{0}` is not valid.", col));
            Item item = ProductSlot[row][col];
            return item;
        }

        double _creditMoney = 0.00;
        public double CreditMoney
        {
            get { return _creditMoney; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("CreditMoney", "CreditMoney cannot be reduced to below $0.00.");
                _creditMoney = value;
            }
        }
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Item>> ProductSlot { get; set; }

        public class Item
        {
            public Item() { }
            public Item(string name, double price, int qty)
            {
                ProductName = name;
                Price = price;
                Quantity = qty;
            }
            private int _quantity = 0;
            public int Quantity 
            {
                get { return _quantity; }
                set
                {
                    if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Quantity", "Quantity cannot be less than zero.");
                    _quantity = value;
                }
            }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }
        }

        public class InsufficientFundsException : Exception
        {
            public InsufficientFundsException() { }
            public InsufficientFundsException(string message)
                : base(message) { }
            public InsufficientFundsException(string message, Exception innerException)
                : base(message, innerException) { }

        }

        public class OutOfStockException : Exception
        {
            public OutOfStockException() { }
            public OutOfStockException(string message)
                : base(message) { }
            public OutOfStockException(string message, Exception innerException)
                : base(message, innerException) { }

        }
    }
}
```